# org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer error in jboss server

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, glassfish

I migrated a project in Ant which runs on glassfish server to maven and server as jboss. I found an exception while deploying the file **org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer**.How can I resolve this.

Comment: How did you install Jersey? By default JBoss uses RESTEasy.

Comment: I didn't install Jersey.In my application which works in glassfish , I used the library's of jersey and I coded  like that.When I migrated the coded to jboss environment its pops up a server error like mentioned above.

Comment: WildFly does not use Jersey as it's JAX-RS implementation. If you're not using any specific Jersey classes and just using the JAX-RS API you should remove the Jersey libraries from your deployment.